# Why do I get "[UITextField hasText]: unrecognized selector"?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uitextfield

On an iPad running iOS 4.3.5 I get this error:

```
MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[UITextField hasText]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6f692d0
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextField.get_HasText () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

And indeed looking at Apple's documentation, there is no "`hasText`" for `UITextField`. But it works, at least on iOS5 devices.
What is going on here? MT is 5.0.1 and the deployment target is set to 4.3. Is this selector new in iOS 5? But why is not documented?

René

Comment: You should look into monotouch documentation instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shivan is right -- `HasText` is a MonoTouch thing.

Here is one place where `HasText` is listed (it was introduced in MonoTouch between 4.2 & 5.0):  http://ios.xamarin.com/Releases/MonoTouch_5/API-diff-from-4.2

If you want `HasText`, you need to run on iOS 5.0 & newer.

Comment: So sad that there is no warning from the compile if the deployment target is set to 4.3! :-(

Answer (score 0):

The HasText property comes from the iOS5 UIKeyInput protocol:

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKeyInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Which UITextField adopts:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html

That is why you see that property in UITextField.

We want to add the checks to either Gendarme, the IDE or the compiler to flag methods that were only introduced in certain versions.   The libraries have this information, it is just not in use right now.

Comment: Then I do not understand the issue: "Available in iOS 3.2 and later." - why would it not work on iOS 4.3?

Comment: The protocol was adopted in 5.0, so it might not exist before in the class.